# Multi-function printer losing wireless connectivity

Tags: wireless-networking, network-printer, wpa

My Richo MP C2550 multi-function printer is losing wireless connectivity.  It is hooked up wirelessly to my home router for printing from two Mac computers at home.

About half the time we can't print and the touch screen on the machine says WPA auth failed.

We keep turning the copier on and off and then "eventually" the message is no longer there and we can print.

Comment: is WPA the only way to connect? Have you tried connecting via SSID and typing your password?

Comment: Printers do not recover from WiFi connection problems as gracefully as PCs do. I recommend using a wired connection for a printer, whenever possible. For reliability, plug the printer into your wireless router and set it up that way. The Macs will still be able to use it.